My relatives and friends who
Is this sentence grammatically correct? Who refers to what ?
My relatives and friends who love me all live elsewhere.
Actually, what I meant to say was this :
My friends who love me and my relatives all live elsewhere.
Does it make more sense to write this way or as above?
I would appreciate if you can give similar examples.

There is nothing wrong with it grammatically, but I would understand it to include your relatives among the people who love you.
If you wish the description to apply only to friends, you can either reverse the order or simply insert a comma after relatives and another after me.
